# "Include as" in C++

Tags: c++, include

I am given a bunch of folders that each have a .cc and a header file in them. The actual names of the files are the same in all folders. So in the case of two folders the structure would be:

```
.
├── f1
│   ├── SomeClass.cc
│   ├── SomeClass.h
└── f2
    ├── SomeClass.cc
    └── SomeClass.h
```

Now unfortunately *SomeClass* is implemented slightly differently in each case and I need to include all different implementations in one file. In Python I could do something like

```
 from .f1.SomeClass import SomeClass as FirstImplementation
 from .f2.SomeClass import SomeClass as SecondImplementation
```

Is there an equivalent for C++?

Comment: hopefully these classes live in some namespace, if not you have a problem anyway

Comment: Unfortunately they don't.

Comment: If you are under control of the other sources, then add a namespace. This would be the C++ equivalent you are looking for...

Comment: Yeah that's kind of the problem. I'm not and it's not just two folders. I mean I could write a script to manually add the namespaces but this would be pretty ugly and I was hoping there would be a nicer way.

Comment: Hm, would not quite match my definition of being under control, if you can write a script to do so... According to mine, you are not if e. g. these files come from some repository (SVN, GIT) and you are not *allowed* to add the namespace because that would break some code elsewhere...

Comment: Well the code is basically the output of some other program, so I have full control over the files but I can't change they way they are written except modify them after they are created.

Comment: C++ has a "One Definition Rule". In the global namespace, there can be only one definition of `::SomeClass`. And C++ has separate compilation - Both copies of `SomeClass.cc` would be compiled independently, not knowing of each others existence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to include them in different namespaces:

create your SomeClass.h:

```
namespace SomeClass1
{
#include "f1/SomeClass.h"
}

namespace SomeClass2
{
#include "f2/SomeClass.h"
}
```

and create your SomeClass.cc:

```
namespace SomeClass1
{
#include "f1/SomeClass.cc"
}

namespace SomeClass2
{
#include "f2/SomeClass.cc"
}
```

But you need to ensure that **all the headers that these four files include** are included before your namespaces. E.g. if they include `<string>`, `<vector>`, `"someHeader.h"` then you need to include  these headers before your `namespace SomeClass1`:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "SomeHeader.h"

namespace SomeClass1
{
...
```

And then try to use them in your code:

```
//instead of #include "f1/SomeClass.h"
#include "SomeClass.h"

SomeClass1::SomeClass c1;
...
SomeClass2::SomeClass c2;
...
```

And now you compile your .cpp file instead of two original files:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp SomeClass.cpp -o main
```

Comment: Would have been my approach, too - I'd do that separately for each .h and .cc file, though...

Comment: @Aconcagua it can be done separately as well. IMO, the most important point is to make sure that other headers aren't included into namespace

Comment: For me `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp f1/SomeClass.cpp f2/SomeClass.cpp -o main` results in `SomeClass.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of SomeClass::SomeClass(std::string)`

Comment: @Lxndr That is exactly what you are not allowed to do! You need to place the classes into different namespaces first and then pass the wrapping files to gcc, *not* the original ones!

Comment: @Lxndr you cannot compile f1/SomeClass.cpp and f2/SomeClass.cpp. You need to create new cpp (and possibly h) file that include these and you should use your new file instead.

Comment: Oh sorry now I get it. Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!