# Visual studio code rename header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clangd

Anyone know how to rename a header file in vscode so that all includes of the header file will be updated accordingly?

For example, if I rename Header0.h to Header1.h, all includes will change from

```
#include "Header0.h"
```

to

```
#include "Header1.h"
```

Use of extensions is also welcome

Comment: I don't know about VS code, what you asking is not supported by Visual Studio IDE. The Rename feature lets you rename identifiers for code symbols, such as fields, local variables, methods, namespaces, properties and types.

Comment: I suggest you to see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799070/include-as-in-c